# github's .gitignore to ignore extensions of .yaml matching the .template extensions

Tags: git, github, ignore

I am looking for a pattern in .ignore for github project.
I want to ignore the .yaml files matching the some .template extensions.

Example in folder `work` I want ignore a.yaml, c.yaml which are matching the a.template and c.template, but not the b.yaml:

`work` :

```
a.yaml
b.yaml
c.yaml
a.template
c.template
```

Is it possible to have such patterns?

Comment: Why do you even need `a.template`? If you want to ignore `a.yaml` then just enter `a.yaml`? I assume *a* & *c* is the file name pattern you want matched?

Comment: YES. I wanted to ignore `.yaml` matching `.template` extensions

Comment: I still don't get why you want to do that when you can just say `.yaml` instead of `.template` and be done with it. What is the reason of having `.template`? If you want to ignore `pattern_a.yaml` just do that, you don't need `pattern_a.template`.

Comment: In my source code `.template` generates the `.yaml`. Example `dir/dir/my.template` will create the `dir/dir/my.yaml` file. I also do have a lot of other.yaml files. I am looking for a pattern which will ignore the `.yaml` generated from` .template`

Comment: Ok, so you're talking about the content from the `.template` file? I don't think dynamic .gitignore is supported. You need to generate list of filenames from `.template` and put them into gitignore or structure your directory tree in such a way that it's easier to ignore.

Answer (score 1):

> I am looking for a pattern which will ignore the `.yaml` generated from`.template`

You would need to script the generation of an adequate `.gitignore`.

There is no dynamic ignore rule done by Git when managing what it is tracking.

The alternative would be to make sure to generate those files in a separate directory than the other static yaml files, that way you can ignore the generated content directory itself.